# I have wrong output from my fixture template

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

```
<?php

$filePath = __DIR__ . '/../../data/cities.csv';
$file = fopen($filePath, 'r');

$cities = [];
$index = 0;

// Skip header line
fgetcsv($file);

while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $cityKey = 'city' . $index;

    // Если мы впервые видим city0, пропустить эту итерацию и перейти к следующей
    if ($cityKey === 'city0') {
        $index++;
        continue;
    }

    $cities[$cityKey] = [
        'name' => $data[0],
        'latitude' => $data[1],
        'longitude' => $data[2],
    ];

    $index++;
}

fclose($file);

return $cities;
```

i have such fixture template, this template creates such

```
   'city0' => [
        'city1' => [
            'name' => 'Абакан',
            'latitude' => '53.7223661',
            'longitude' => '91.4437792',
        ],
        'city2' => [
            'name' => 'Абдулино',
            'latitude' => '53.6778096',
            'longitude' => '53.6473115',
        ],
```

structure, to be correct i need to remove 'city0' => [, how i can do this?

```
  if ($cityKey === 'city0') {
        $index++;
        continue;
    }
```

This code does not help
Also in the end of generating i got this

```
      'city1086' => [
            'name' => 'Яхрома',
            'latitude' => '56.2889858',
            'longitude' => '37.4831016',
        ],
    ],
    'city1' => [
        'city1' => [
            'name' => 'Абакан',
            'latitude' => '53.7223661',
            'longitude' => '91.4437792',
        ],
```

so i need to remove the second part that starts

```
'city1' => [
```

I wrote all the code, but can not remove this code

```
'city0' => [
```

from the fixture output, also when i generated city list once, then i got second generated part after i got item with [0][1086] index.

Comment: IMHO you are trying to use fixture generator in wrong way. The generator uses templates to create pseudo-random data for tests. But in your case you already have data in CSV format and you are trying to use generator to convert it from CSV to PHP array. Instead of converting it, it might be better to simply override `getData()` method in fixture class to read data from CSV file directly. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-test-activefixture#getData()-detail

Comment: Just check if this key exist in the array and unset it.